# Issue Getting Attachments from Email in Microsoft Flow/Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm currently building a new ticketing system for my workplace. When an email is received it generates a ticket number and few files in a SharePoint document library. One of those folders is "Attachments" where the flow I am building is supposed to put any attached documents. As far as I can tell I've followed other guides to the tee, however it renders the attachments un-openable. After downloading the files it did make and opening them in Notepad++, the content of the files is completely different and I can't seem to figure out why... I've been testing mostly with *.docx files, but it does the same for other file types as well. Please see attached screenshot of the attachments getter part of the flow. Any support is greatly appreciated!

[Attachment Getter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldxkR.png)

Note: This is how the guides told me to do it, however I did try changing the "File Content" box to "Attachments Content" instead of "Current Item" from the dynamic content menu to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try use attachments content directly:
[image]
[How to save Email Attachments to your SharePoint Document Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpWp9Dh4mhQ)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to get the file content.
File content should help getting attachment. You will have to recreate a file though.

Comment: It's an email attachment so there's no file to get the content of without using the dynamic content that comes from the email received trigger, at least not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, please check if you have set the value of `Include Attachments` in the trigger to `Yes`.
[image]

Comment: @Starspiker Set to "Yes" and still same error ? I reproduced the same issue if I set to "No". If it still shows same error, could you please provided more details (such as the screenshot of your trigger) ? And my I know which connector did you use, Office365 or Outlook connector ?